# How to assign a value to a bind() in asp.net <inserttemplate>

Tags: asp.net

```
<InsertItemTemplate>
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ProductId") %>'>
    </asp:TextBox>
</InsertItemTemplate>
```

How do I pass a value to the Bind("ProductId")? More specifically:

```
Request.QueryString["ProductId"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT:

leave it with your original bind but add OnDataBinding

```
  <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ProductId") %>'
    OnDataBinding = "TextBox1_OnDataBinding"></asp:TextBox>
```

and

```
    protected void TextBox1_OnDataBinding(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       (sender as TextBox).Text = Request.QueryString["ProductId"];
    }
```

Comment: I've tried that it doesn't actually pass the value to the parameter to the object that objectdatasource uses.

Comment: @Odnxe you are trying to display ProductId from QueryString in the textbox and you want to send the textbox value back to datasource when you save?

Comment: @StackOverflowException - Yes basically I want to take the value from the URL Parameter "ProductId=?" and assign that value to the Textbox, which connects to the database through the bind()

Comment: @Odnxe I don't think you can do that with `Bind()`

Answer (score 0):

In addition to

```
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%#Request.QueryString["ProductID"]%>' />
```

You need to handle the OnInserting event of your datasource and set the value there with the querystring parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to explicitly set the TextBox value in the DataBound event of your DataBoundControl (repeater/gv etc).